# Migrate from CMS Made Simple to Wordpress

Tags: migration

I am trying to convert a website on [CMS Made Simple](http://www.cmsmadesimple.de/) ([GitHub account](https://github.com/cmsmadesimple)) onto Wordpress. I have researched online extensively only to find no substantial content to help me.

Is there a potential script that can perform this migration? If not, could someone explain the steps to follow in order to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't meet any ready-made script for CMS Made Simple to Wordpress conversion, but I've found out that [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#.D0.A1MS_Made_Simple) has a listed service for it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if `Joomla` and `CMS Made Simple` are similar, but I did a migration from `Joomla` Website (very old version) to `WordPress`.

For this, I did many queries in `SQL` to copy the content from `Joomla` to `WordPress`.

If you have a good knowledge on tables of `WordPress` & `CMS Made Simple`, maybe you can do this.

Migration of content from Joomla to WordPress:

```
INSERT INTO wp_posts(`post_author`,`post_date`,`post_content`,`post title`, `post_modified`)
SELECT `created_by`,`created`,`introtext`,`title`,`modified` FROM jos_content
```